# JFreeChart TimeSeries Axis in non-military time

Tags: java, time-series, jfreechart, renjin

I am trying to graph `TimeSeries` data in Java using `JFreeChart`, however the data consists of doubles that are the output of calls to [`Renjin`](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/introduction.html). The code to add the data to the `TimeSeries` is as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<series2Values.length; i++) {
    if (!Double.isNaN(series2Values[i])) {
        series2.add(new Hour((int)times[i], new Day()), series2Values[i]);
    } else {
        series2.add(new Hour((int)times[i], new Day()), null);
    }
}

final TimeSeriesCollection dataset2 = new TimeSeriesCollection();
dataset2.addSeries(series2);

JFreeChart chart2 = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(title, "Time (Hour)", "Vehicles Parked", dataset2, true, true, false);
ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame(title, chart2, false);
frame2.pack();
frame2.setIconImage(img.getImage());
frame2.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is that whenever the data is graphed, the times on the X axis are displayed in 24-hour military time, and if the `time[]` array contains any duplicate values the following `SeriesException` is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jfree.data.general.SeriesException: You are attempting to add an observation for the time period [6,12/7/2016] but the series already contains an observation for that time period. Duplicates are not permitted.  Try using the addOrUpdate() method.
```

The `addOrUpdate()` method recommended by the Exception will just overwrite the first data point in place for that time 12 hours earlier rather than making a new one. I would like to instead display the data in the 12-hour format with AM and PM shown.

Is there a convenient way to do this with `JFreeChart`, or would it be more convenient to change the code so that my calls to `Renjin` return something formatted, rather than just plain integers between 1 and 24? (e.g. already formatted time strings)?

[Cross-posted here.](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117621&p=179881#p179881)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Renjin`, but assuming a `Date` value representing milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time),

1. Use [`setDateFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride-java.text.DateFormat-) on the axis with a suitable [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), e.g.

   ```
   axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"));
   ```
2. [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) "will ensure…that each period appears at most one time in the series." This should become moot if the incoming value is converted correctly.

Comment: Worked great, I had to do a bit of casting and this was the final line of code I had to use `((DateAxis)chart2.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis()).setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"));`